# PostgreSQL 9.2.4-x64 installation problems on windows 8 Pro 64bit

Tags: installation, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on Windows 8 Pro 64, but nearly the end of the installation problem I am keep getting this error

> "Problem running prop-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly The database cluster installation failed."

I tried to install it few times, with firewall turned off, I also deleted 'postgres' user that is created for PostgreSQL. But I am keep getting this message.

I also tried with older versions. 9.1, 9.0 but I am keep getting the same problems.

Any one with similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Place in the folder on PostgreSQL security administrator permissions for the user of your machine and try to install again it will work

Comment: ... still the same outcome ... I don't know what is happening, on Windows 7 works perfectly, On Ubuntu also, but on Windows 8 Pro there are problems.

Comment: Just to update this question. After updating windows 8 to windows 8.1 the issues with PostgreSQL are no longer present, just like that.